# Host Asp.Net Web API as an Application Under Asp.Net MVC application on IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-web-api

I Have an ASP.NET MVC web application which is hosted as a new site on iis. I have another ASP.NET Web API which I need to host under the MVC app as an application. However, when I host and try to access the web api I get the following error.

[Link to image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4K8B.jpg)

However when I host the Web Api as a different site on iis it works fine. Any idea on how to resolve this ?

Comment: According to the error message you provided, this may be because Web api cannot find DevExpress, the version of DevExpress in Web api and DevExpress in MVC may be different, you need to check the version of DevExpress. You can also add a new site for web api.

Comment: The Web Api does not have any DevExpress references. However, managed to resolve this issue by setting  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false"> on the web.config of the MVC Application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved by setting inheritInChildApplications="false" on the web.config file of the Asp.net MVC Application.

```
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.web></system.web>
  </location>

  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer></system.webServer>
  </location>
```